# Spring boot custom JWT filter not allowing any request without token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jwt

I'm using custom JWT filter with spring boot security configuration to allow certain API requests without JWT token. But permitAll() method in WebSecurity configuration is not working (not allowing any requests without JWT).It throws custom InvalidJwtException. What i'm missing here? I've tried lot of google search but got no success.

WebSecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
class WebSecurityConfig(
    private val jwtTokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider,
    private val filterChainExceptionHandler: FilterChainExceptionHandler,
) : WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter() {

    override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {

        http?.csrf()?.disable()
        http?.sessionManagement()?.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)

        http
            ?.authorizeRequests()
            ?.antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/signin")?.permitAll()
            ?.antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/checkEmailExist")?.permitAll()
            ?.anyRequest()?.authenticated()

        http
            ?.addFilterBefore(JwtTokenFilter(jwtTokenProvider), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter::class.java)
            ?.addFilterBefore(filterChainExceptionHandler, JwtTokenFilter::class.java)

    }

    @Bean
    fun passwordEncoder(): PasswordEncoder {
        return BCryptPasswordEncoder(10)
    }

    @Bean
    override fun authenticationManagerBean(): AuthenticationManager {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean()
    }
}
```

JwtTokenFilter class

```
@Component
class JwtTokenFilter(
    private val jwtTokenProvider: JwtTokenProvider
) : OncePerRequestFilter() {

    override fun doFilterInternal(
        request: HttpServletRequest,
        response: HttpServletResponse,
        filterChain: FilterChain
    ) {
        try {
            val token = jwtTokenProvider.resolveToken(request)
            if (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)) {
                val auth = jwtTokenProvider.getAuthentication(token)
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().authentication = auth
            }
        } catch (e: InvalidJwtException) {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()
            throw InvalidJwtException(e.message, e.httpStatus)
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response)
    }
}
```

ResolveToken function

```
 fun resolveToken(req: HttpServletRequest): String? {
        val bearerToken = req.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)
        return if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith(BEARER)) {
            bearerToken.substring(7)
        } else {
            throw InvalidJwtException("Authorization token must be Bearer [token]", HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN)
        }
 }
```

Comment: That is what your own code is doing, when no token, throw exception. As this is always executed before any rule checking it will always throw this exception. Hence don't throw an exception.

Comment: Ain't this lines should allow both request without token? as it have permitAll ()antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/signin")?.permitAll()
antMatchers("/api/v1/auth/checkEmailExist")?.permitAll()

Comment: No. It always access regardless of who it is. However the determine who requires authentication and that is invoked before the `permitAll` is evaluated. If you want to disable all filters (not recommended) configure web security to `ignore` certain URL's **however** this disables **all** security filters for that URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You token validation should exclude authentication URLs:

```
if (!request.getRequestURL().toString().contains("auth") || (token != null && jwtTokenProvider.validateToken(token)))
```

You can choose a better String to identify that excluded paths than "auth" that I've used